# A single cloud project for each environment?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-roles, azure-configuration

Previously I have always had separate cloud projects for each environment, like this:

[image: Cloud Project layout]

This poses some problems:

- Maintaining multiple `ServiceDefinition.csdef` files
- When building to a common output path, which `ServiceDefinition.csdef` is copied?

I am proposing using a single Cloud Project with multiple `ServiceConfiguration` files for each environment, and multiple profiles for publishing:

[image: Single Cloud Project]

Pros:

- Less maintenance issues (1 project and 1 `ServiceDefinition.csdef`)
- A single `ServiceDefinition.csdef` is copied to the output folder

The problem I have now is that all environments need to have the **same instance size** as this is defined in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef`.

Is there any way I can get around this problem?

Comment: Consider using powershell for deployment (build the package with cspack). Then you can patch the definitions for each specific environment before you build the package.

Comment: Our build server is currently creating a package from the ServiceDefinition.  Do you create multiple packages? One for each environment?  How do you patch the definition before creating the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we create multiple packages (one for each environment). We have different powershell scripts to patch things like the vm-size (one example):

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$fileToPatch,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$roleName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [validateSet("ExtraSmall", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "ExtraLarge", "A5", "A6", "A7")]
    [string]$vmsize = 'Small'
)
#  MAIN

$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load($fileToPatch)

$namespaceMgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
$namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)

$xpathWorkerRoles = "/ns:ServiceDefinition/ns:WorkerRole"
$xpathWebRoles = "/ns:ServiceDefinition/ns:WebRole"
$Roles = $xml.SelectNodes($xpathWebRoles, $namespaceMgr) + $xml.SelectNodes($xpathWorkerRoles, $namespaceMgr)

$Roles | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $RoleName} | % { $_.vmsize = $vmsize; Write-Host 'Patched vmsize to' $vmsize 'for' $_.name } 

$xml.Save($fileToPatch)
```